# Removing all subfolders older than 3 days inside a folder, but keep the main folder

Tags: bash, shell, find, exec, rm

I have a directory structure like this:

news_images folder -> subfolder with current date ex. 20140626 -> files

I would like to remove all subfolders with files inside news_images directory that are older than 3 days.

This does remove only files inside news_images directory but do not touch the subfolders.

```
find news_images -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What if you have a folder that hasn't been modified in 10 days, but it has a file in it that was modified yesterday?

Comment: Also, any time you remove a file, it sets the folder's modification time to now. So after removing old files from the folder, the folder itself won't look old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rm without options is not able to delete directories. Try option -r.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to find only subdirectories of news_images (then remove them recursively) ?
Something like (not tested but I think it should work):

```
find news_images -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```